# mobile safari rendering buttons with border

Tags: html, css, safari, rendering, mobile-safari

I have a set of buttons and they are rendering strangely in mobile safari. There is an uneven border around each one.

[image: uneven border image]

That is how they appear on mobile safari, and below is how they appear in every other browser.

[image: no border]

The code I have for the buttons is:

```
        <div id="buttonbox">
    <div id="button1" class="buttons"><a href="one/two-wrong.html?">2 CHOICE1</a></div>
    <div id="button2" class="buttons"><a href="one/two-wrong.html?">2 CHOICE2</a></div>
    <div id="button3" class="buttons"><a href="one/two-right.html?">2 CHOICE3</a></div>
    <div id="button4" class="buttons"><a href="one/two-wrong.html?">2 CHOICE4</a></div>
</div>

   #buttonbox{
    position:relative; 
    top:500px;           
    padding:40px;
    }

    .buttons a{
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;   
    }

    .buttons, .buttons:active, .buttons:focus{
     border:none;
    outline:none;

    }

    .buttons{
    background-color:#aaa;
    outline:none;
    border:none;
    width:100px;
    padding:5px;
    opacity:0;   


    animation: buttonFade;
    animation-iteration-count: once;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-delay:2s;


    -webkit-animation-name: buttonFade;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: once;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:2s; 
    }

    @keyframes buttonFade {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes buttonFade {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
    }
```

I am not sure if there is a way to get around this, as it seems to be a safari problem, but I would really appreciate any advice!

Comment: Have you tried `-webkit-appearance: none;`?

Comment: i have, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: maybe `border: 0px;` rather than `border: none;`?

Comment: changing to 0px doesn't have any effect either.