# CSS border-width:1px doesn't give me equally thin borders

Tags: css

I am trying add thin borders to a `div`. My CSS is like this:

```
border: solid;
border-width: 1px;
```

Yet the result borders don't look equally thin in my browser. As you can see below, the borders on the left and bottom look thicker than the borders on the right and top.

[image]

I want to make the borders equally thin. I have tried to add

```
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
```

But it doesn't change the look. [JS Fiddle example here.](https://jsfiddle.net/3sww4wnt/)

I tried this in my Chrome Version 41.0.2272.101 m -- it looks bad. I've also tried this in IE -- it looks fine. So I know it's not my monitor...

Comment: It seems fine in Chrome 41. Can't see any issue.

Comment: This is not what `shape-rendering` is used for (and it has no effect). What browser are you looking at this in? I can't find the one that replicates your issue.

Comment: Try updating your Chrome, looks fine to me.

Comment: looks good to me in chrome: http://screencast.com/t/bpqcQbmr

Comment: I have Chrome 41.0.2272.101 m (up to date). I still have this problem. In my IE it looks fine, so I know it's not my monitor -- it's Chrome... @HashemQolami

Comment: Well at least now you know it looks fine to the rest of us :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your monitor is set to a non-native resolution. (Windows 8) Right click on your desktop, click "Screen Resolution" and then select the recommended resolution.

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem.
After some research I found out it's caused by 1.5 device pixel ratio (Windows 8.1 set scale everything to 150%).

Solution is to set sale to 100% but it makes texts supertiny so I can't use this solution.

Both IE(11) and Chrome are affected. Firefox is OK.

Same issue is goes for mobile phones and tablets:

[mobile safari rendering buttons with border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711152/mobile-safari-rendering-buttons-with-border)

[Uneven border in mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297434/uneven-border-in-mobile-browsers)

Answer (score -2):

You likely have other elements to the left and below the box and may be accidentally applying borders to them as well to make it appear that they have "double" borders.

Make sure you isolate the box and try again.

A 1px border can't be uneven like you are displaying.

Comment: Even perfectly vertical 1px lines can be uneven on screen due to subpixel positioning, page zoom, non-native resolution, operating system scaling, and even non-rectangular sub pixels in extreme case. This is not a new phenomenon, ever since we have subpixel html rendering we have this problem.