# Weird Chrome border radius font size bug

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Sorry about the  confusing title but this bug is just strange.

I am working on some buttons and noticed that if my button has a border + border radius + overlay ( used for gradients ) on specific font size Chrome is displaying 2 px right border instead of 1 .

[image]

Here is fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3x73q9md/

I am not sure if my overlay container is inheriting something but I cant find the fix except changing the font size.

Also tried

```
font:0/0 a;
```

on overlay container and all sorts of CSS hacks but this just makes no sense.

The button is relative and overlay absolute stretched in all directions.

Can someone please explain what this is.

**Please note that I am not asking to add/remove/modify current html structure. Just need to understand why this is happening and possible solution for it.**

Comment: Are you zoomed in 100%? (ALT + 0)

Comment: This renders normally for me in Windows on Chrome 45.

Comment: @Chris , 100% , tested that also several times

Comment: It renders normally for me as well. It does render a 2px right border when I zoom in to 110%.

Comment: Maybe got to do with your screen resolution settings in Windows. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379559/css-border-width1px-doesnt-give-me-equally-thin-borders

Comment: @Paulo ,  that confirms it that it is connected to font size. As displayed in fiddle. If you zoom to 110% you see it. I see it by default. This should not be happening. Thnx for testing.

Comment: Agreed. Have you tried different Chrome versions or screen densities in you computer?

Comment: @PauloAvelar testing the Chris suggestion , seems like it is win 10 default font setting. Mine is 125%

Comment: I see, it may be due to high resolutions -- Windows manages it so that the UI won't get too small to be usable. I've tested on Windows 7 @ 1366x768 (work laptop). I'll follow up on this when I get home and try to reproduce it in my personal laptop running W10. But I'd say that's the issue.

Comment: Chris or Paulo , post an answer so that I can accept it . This seems to be connected to win10 font size + chrome

Answer (score 0):

change .overlay class **border-radius: inherit;** to **border-radius:0;**

```
     .overlay {border-radius:0;}
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/3x73q9md/1/

Comment: cant do that since i need to add some transition to the overlay , and it must inherit the br from parent. but either way with 0  I still see the bug