# Difference of pixel in border I can't figure where it is coming from

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm doing a really simple navigator but I just came up into a strange problem I can't figure out where this is coming from.

My separations are not exactly till, they are created the same way..
Some are tougher than other and I don't get why.

[image]

Could it be due to the font ? I tried it with different browser and the problem is persistent...

**[JsFiddle There](https://jsfiddle.net/bccck40r/1/)**

The code is really simple :

**HTML**

```
<nav id="main-menu2">
  <a href="/"><span class="fa fa-home"></span></a>
  <a href="/">DERNIÈRES MINUTES</a>
  <a href="/">SÉJOURS</a>
  <a href="/">CROISIÈRES</a>
  <a href="/">CIRCUITS</a>
  <a href="/">FRANCE</a>
  <a href="/">WEEK-ENDS</a>
  <a href="/">VOYAGE À LA CARTE</a>
  <a href="/">PROMOS</a>
</nav>
```

**SCSS**

```
$darkOrange: #ed6d00;
#main-menu2 {
  background-color: $darkOrange;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    margin-left: -2px;
    margin-right: -2px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    line-height: 1.7em;
  }
  .fa-home{
    font-size: 23px;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS border-width:1px doesn't give me equally thin borders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379559/css-border-width1px-doesnt-give-me-equally-thin-borders)

Comment: for me, eveything looks fine... what browser and so on are you using?

Comment: @FalcoB Chrome but anyway I took it in screenshot, the screenshot does not look fine yeah ?

Comment: @Sheepy possibly but I tried it in FF and still had the problem

Comment: @Baldráni Uneven border thickness due to subpixel positioning happens to most browsers.  But enguerranws seems to have spend the time to find your the real cause. Congrats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the bug, but I may have a solution : **you're currently using borders that you don't need**. Let me explain : *there is a border right on Séjours and a border left on Croisières. So 2 borders, and you're currently hiding one of them.*

Using font-size in `em`, makes your trick (margin-left / margin-right : -2px) unconsistent, because em can't really be converted into px (well it can, but it will depends on the browser calculation so you may need more than 2px to make a border go over another, maybe 1px maybe 1.5487px).

**So, my solution : removes all the unecessary borders :**

```
a {
   border-left: 1px solid #fff;
} 
a:last-child {
   border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

*No more borders overlapping, more reliable solution.*

Comment: It does indeed do the trick but my question is more like why does this happen.

Comment: It's explained in the 2nd paragraphe. Some browsers (Chrome e.g.) mess up with pixel conversion (from % or em) and doesn't round it. So if you go further inspecting, you could see some dimensions like 25.5458px. Not sure if I'm clear in my explanation, sorry.

Comment: I've had this issue a lot with Chrome, you're welcome.

Comment: It actually resolved an other of my problem ! Morality try to avoid `em` as much as possible!

Comment: Well, no. Em is a good thing and can be very useful, it's just that the calculation of the render can be unconsistent depending on the browser (and the reset CSS you use). But in your case, the issue comes from the wrong implementation of borders (2 instead of 1), not ems.

Comment: Well I still need two for the effect on hover It is a matter of pixel but I see it and if I can see it a client could see it too.

Comment: If you need an effect on hover state, you can still put only one border per element (and the other would be transparent), then on :hover, change the color of the transparent border (its position, and whatever). But I'm pretty sure you don't need to show 2 borders when you need one :)

Answer (score 1):

Manage it with the `font-size`:

```
#main-menu2 {
    font-size: 0;
}

#main-menu2 a {
    font-size: 14.5px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

The whole code:

```
$darkOrange: #ed6d00;
#main-menu2 {
  background-color: $darkOrange;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 14.5px;
    line-height: 1.7em;
  }
  .fa-home{
    font-size: 23px;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    }
}
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bccck40r/3/)

It is because in your code you have some space by indent the text. Unfortunately all browsers interprete these content as white spaces and thus you have some gap between the elements.